# Selenium Connection Reset: Unable to find an exact match for CDP version 96, so returning the closest version found: 95

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Stack Trace:

```
Starting ChromeDriver 96.0.4664.45 (76e4c1bb2ab4671b8beba3444e61c0f17584b2fc-refs/branch-heads/4664@{#947}) on port 58050
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
Nov 20, 2021 9:34:48 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
Nov 20, 2021 9:34:49 AM org.openqa.selenium.devtools.CdpVersionFinder findNearestMatch
WARNING: Unable to find an exact match for CDP version 96, so returning the closest version found: 95
Nov 20, 2021 9:34:49 AM org.openqa.selenium.devtools.CdpVersionFinder findNearestMatch
INFO: Found CDP implementation for version 96 of 95
Nov 20, 2021 9:36:34 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.WebSocket$Listener onError
WARNING: Connection reset
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.throwConnectionReset(SocketChannelImpl.java:394)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:426)
    at io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBuf.setBytes(PooledByteBuf.java:253)
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:1132)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:350)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:151)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:719)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:655)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:581)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:986)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
```

I am making a java selenium bot and when I start the bot it says connection reset after the last line of the code

I get this error even though my

- Chrome version = 96
- Driver version = 96

Please help

Here is the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        //region GUI
        int loginTimeOutDuration = 100000;
        int chatLoadingDelay = 1000;
        String serverID = "707324806856572949";
        String message = "Hi!";
        //endregion

        System.setProperty
                ("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\\\Users\\\\~~~~~\\\\Downloads\\\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

        String baseUrl = "https://discord.com/channels/" + serverID + "/";

        driver.get(baseUrl);
        Thread.sleep(loginTimeOutDuration);
        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/" +
                "div/div[2]/div[2]/div/aside/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]"));

        Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
        actions.contextClick(element).perform();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[5]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]")).click();

        driver.close();
    }
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add "urgent" or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) and find out why it often has the opposite effect.

Answer (score 3):

This error message...

```
Nov 20, 2021 9:34:49 AM org.openqa.selenium.devtools.CdpVersionFinder findNearestMatch
WARNING: Unable to find an exact match for CDP version 96, so returning the closest version found: 95
Nov 20, 2021 9:34:49 AM org.openqa.selenium.devtools.CdpVersionFinder findNearestMatch
INFO: Found CDP implementation for version 96 of 95
Nov 20, 2021 9:36:34 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.WebSocket$Listener onError
WARNING: Connection reset
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
```

...implies that the *ChromeDriver* was unable to initiate/spawn a new *Browsing Context* i.e. *Chrome Browser* session and *`java.net.SocketException: Connection reset`* occured.

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- Though you are using *chromedriver=96.0*
- Possibly you are using [***Selenium v4.0.0***](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/201fad38296f9ea47ac1b1b59c160963dc7b2907/java/CHANGELOG#L21) which:

> - Supported CDP versions: 85, 93, 94, 95

Hence, you see:

```
WARNING: Unable to find an exact match for CDP version 96, so returning the closest version found: 95
```

---

### Solution

Ensure that:

- Selenium is upgraded to current [v4.1.0](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/201fad38296f9ea47ac1b1b59c160963dc7b2907/java/CHANGELOG#L1) where:

> - Supported CDP versions: 85, 94, 95, 96

Comment: it worked for me! Double check Selenium version and that's it.

Answer (score 0):

> This SocketException occurs on the server side when the client closed
> the socket connection before the response could be returned over the
> socket. For example, by quitting the browser before the reponse was
> retrieved.

discord.com uses Websocket communication, when you connect, `wss://remote-auth-gateway.discord.gg/?v=1`
Waiting for certification. (socket is alive)

Maybe `driver.close()` closed the the socket.